# Problems applying AMBARI to existing system

Tags: hadoop, centos6, ambari, bigdata

I'm going to apply AMBARI to my system.
But my system already has hadoop.
How do I add existing Hadoop clusters to my new AMBARI environment
Sorry for my English.

Comment: I think it is not possible to use existing hadoop cluster with Ambari.

Answer (score 0):

Ambari can only manage clusters that it provisioned. Your pre-existing hadoop cluster was not provisioned with Ambari so it cannot be managed by Ambari.

Ambari is designed around a Stack concept where each stack consists of several services. A stack definition is what allows Ambari to install, manage and monitor the services in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do right now because already hadoop is installed in the system and you want to apply AMBARI over that for managing the hadoop cluster that's not possible.

Detailed description about the Apache Ambari :---

The Apache Ambari project is aimed at making Hadoop management simpler by developing software for provisioning, managing, and monitoring Apache Hadoop clusters. Ambari provides an intuitive, easy-to-use Hadoop management web UI backed by its RESTful APIs.

Ambari enables System Administrators to:

**Provision a Hadoop Cluster**

Ambari provides a step-by-step wizard for installing Hadoop services across any number of hosts.
   Ambari handles configuration of Hadoop services for the cluster.

**Manage a Hadoop Cluster**

Ambari provides central management for starting, stopping, and reconfiguring Hadoop services across the entire cluster.

**Monitor a Hadoop Cluster**

Ambari provides a dashboard for monitoring health and status of the Hadoop cluster.

Ambari leverages Ambari Metrics System for metrics collection.

Ambari leverages Ambari Alert Framework for system alerting and will notify you when your attention is needed (e.g., a node goes down, remaining disk space is low, etc).